# Как получить с i-ой по j-ую строчки?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, limit

Делаю выборку, но вывести нужно не все строчки, а только с i-ой по j-ую строчки. База данных MySQL.

Например с 11-ой по 20-ю.

Comment: Добавьте Limit 11,10

Comment: @splash58 `limit 11,10` выберет строки с 12 по 21

Comment: Передавать в хранимую процедуру `i` и `j`, а затем использовать технику, рекомендованную коллегами в ответах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select * from table limit 10, 10`

limit N,M: где N - номер строки с которой начинается вывод (отсчет идет от 0), а M - кол-во строк которые необходимо вывести.

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
SELECT * FROM records LIMIT 10,10
```

UPD:

В операторе LIMIT первое число это смещение, а второе -- количество выбираемых строк. Подробнее: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html